# How can I show $g'=0$ everywhere?

Tags: complex-analysis

Does  there  exist a  function $f$,  analytic  in the  punctured plane $ \mathbb{C} \setminus\{0\}$ , such  that $|f(z)|  \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{|z|}}$ for all non zero $z?$

**My attempt** : Take $g(z)\le \sqrt{|z|}$.Fix  $z$ , choose $R >|z|$  and  let  $C_R$ be the circle  with centre  $0$  and  radius $R$

Then  $$g'(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C_r} \frac {g(w)}{(w-z)^2} dw$$

**My question** : How can I show $g'=0$  everywhere?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/325588/42969

Comment: @MartinR I am taking a different approach. In my case, I am using a cauchy integral  formula.

Comment: In g modulus is missing.

Comment: your attempt thus far is to state the definition for Cauchy Integral Formula (CIF) but this is not an accurate definition since the curve (/cycle) $\gamma$ that generates $C_r$ winds once around $0$ yet $0$ is not known to be in your domain.  My suggestion: (1) argue that $0$ is a removable singularity for $g$, so $g$ may be taken to be an entire function; (2) since you want to use CIF: (i) using CIF argue all derivatives at 0 must be zero for $g$ [apply ML Inequality and consider for arbitrarily large $r$] or (ii) argue $g'(z)=0$ for all $z$ in unit disc by CIF and ML Inequality.